# How to remove .php extension on firebase hosted webpage?

Tags: php, html, firebase, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I have problem with rewriting urls on my webpage which is hosted with firebase.
This is how my firebase.json looks.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": true,
    "headers": [ {
      "source": "*.php",
      "headers": [ {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/html"
      } ]
    } ],
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**/!(*.css|*.js|*.map|*.jpg|*.gif|*.png|*.php),/post/**",

        "dynamicLinks": true
       
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

So far so good. The problem that I have that's not working.
When my webpage is hosted for example on https://google.com

And my inner page for contact  are at the moment on https://google.com/contact.php

This is working  but that's not working https://google.com/contact
But that's what I want. Also maybe you can check If I do it correct with giving 2 rules for rewriting first one is this on

```
"**/!(*.css|*.js|*.map|*.jpg|*.gif|*.png|*.php)",
```

Second is this one

```
/post/**
```

Can I write it togehter or should I do a own rewrite tag for

```
/post/**
```

Comment: Firebase Hosting does not serve/interpret PHP code. Are you sure the filename extension is your main problem here?

Comment: Yes it is with the Headers Firebase firebase reads the php code as html I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61963981/is-there-a-way-to-serve-a-php-file-as-html-on-firebase-hosting.   So it works I can see that it works . But im not know why still without .php web server cannot find the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest that Firebase Hosting offers is the `"cleanUrls": true` option, which you already set. But that only removes `.html` extensions. This is by design, as `.html` files are typically served as static content with their full URL showing in the browser.

Firebase Hosting does not interpret PHP code in any way, so most likely it is serving your PHP code as plain text to your site visitors. If there is no PHP code in your files, rename them to `.html` at which point the `"cleanUrls": true` option will remove the extension.

Comment: van Puffeln as i said i used php code first it was displayed as plain text but now with the headers tag its showing correct . Because the headers tag rewrite it as html. But the .php extension is still there .